# jQuery onload and resize with cookie set

Tags: jquery, class, cookies, resize, pageload

Looking for a bit of help to add to what I have already. What I have working is an onLoad and Resize swap to a particular class which alters the grid for different resolutions. What I need is a cookie to be set so the grid remains persistent when going from page to page.

```
    // swaps the grid span names when the resolution goes below 1200px
    // or when page is loaded below 1200px

     $(window).bind("load resize", function(){

        var width = $(window).width(),
        bodycontent_grid = width < 1200 ? 'span8' :
                    width > 1200 ? 'span6' : '';
         rightcol_grid = width < 1200 ? 'span3' :
                    width > 1200 ? 'span5' : '';

        $('.bodycontent').removeClass('span6 span8').addClass(bodycontent_grid),
        $('.rightcol').removeClass('span3 span5').addClass(rightcol_grid);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS based solution is not very good (read on) but anyway I will try to answer the question about the cookies first:

You could use some kind of [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) or just plain JS which is a bit harder.
jQuery syntax is:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value'); // storing cookie
$.cookie('name'); // reading cookie
```

Using that you could change your source code to something like this:

```
function resizeContainer(var force=false) // additional parameter is used to force resetting cookie
{
    var width;
    if($.cookie('knownWidth') && !force) // if there's a cookie and we're not forcing reset, use width from cookie
    {
        width = $.cookie('knownWidth');
    }
    else
    {
        width = $(window).width();
        $.cookie('knownWidth', width);
    }
    var bodycontent_grid = width < 1200 ? 'span8' :
                width > 1200 ? 'span6' : '';
     rightcol_grid = width < 1200 ? 'span3' :
                width > 1200 ? 'span5' : '';

    $('.bodycontent').removeClass('span6 span8').addClass(bodycontent_grid),
    $('.rightcol').removeClass('span3 span5').addClass(rightcol_grid);
}

$(window).bind("load", function(){
    resizeContainer(); // onload use cookie
});
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    resizeContainer(true); // when resizing force changing the cookie
});
```

Of cource, the cookie can be accessed on the server side and then containers could be generated with appriopriate classes on the server side.

**I must say I don't like the solution using cookies.** There's so much talking about [responsive web design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/), so why don't you use CSS [@media-queries](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)?

You could do something like this in your .css file:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    /* Styles when over 1200px */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    /* Styles when under 1200px */
}
```

By the way, try resizing browser window when you're on http://bostonglobe.com/ or http://smashingmagazine.com :) It's pure CSS!